# PHP using exit() inside a function() to return only 1 value at a time

Tags: php, function, return, exit

Suppose I have written the following function to check empty posted values:

```
function checkEmpty($postValue, $msg){
  if($postValue == null){
    return alert_danger($msg);
    exit(); // NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED
  }
}
```

And I am trying to call it for several input values this way:

```
echo checkEmpty($city, "City cannot be empty");
echo checkEmpty($phone, "phone cannot be empty");
echo checkEmpty($name, "name cannot be empty");
```

Now when I call this function above it echoes all the three values as it should be but I do not want that. I want it to return 1 error at a time. If `city` is empty it should return `City cannot be empty` only and not the others. When the user has corrected the error it should then proceed to check the next error. But it seems that the `exit()` used inside the function is not working as expected. I could use the following method:

```
if($name == null){
  echo alert_danger("Please enter your Name.");
  exit();
}

if($email == null){
  echo alert_danger("Please enter your Email ID.");
  exit();
}

if($phone == null){
  echo alert_danger("Please enter your Phone number.");
  exit();
}
```

But that makes the code too big unnecessarily if I have 15-20 variables to be checked. That's why I wanted to use the function method here as tried earlier. What should be the solution?

Comment: Personally I would find this method of correcting data a bit annoying.  I would rather get a list of all of the problems so that I can fix them and then go onto the next thing.  Having to fix one error to be then told about another error is just tedious.

Comment: `exit(); // NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED` - the reason is this never gets executed, `return` terminates function execution. P.S. I second Nigel's statement. This is terrible user experience.

Comment: Yes you are right in and that helps in many cases. But getting list of 10-15 red alert boxes one after the other at one time that pushes form below the view port is equally annoying in most of the cases too. And what if you are using Modal Alert Boxes? Therefore, in my view, both the method has their own advantages and disadvantages as far as user experience is concerned. Right? And also, my method here gives one extra advantage to the developers that the code becomes light and easier for future use rather than using conditional statements again and again. So I will prefer this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function that echoes the error then dies after:

```
function checkEmpty($postValue, $msg){
    if($postValue == null){
        echo alert_danger($msg);
        exit();
    }
}

checkEmpty($city, "City cannot be empty"); //without echo
```

Comment: Oh yes! holy crap why couldn't I think of this. Thanks for pointing that out man. Bless you :)